# Javascript + 7 days ( Only want dd-mm-yy)

Tags: javascript, datetime

I want to change this date to be formatted to DD-MM-YY

```
new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)))
```

Current result: Thu Sep 15 2022 02:16:38 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

Wanted result: 15-09-22

Comment: So get the 3 values and display them however you want. MDN has docs for the Date datatype, including its member functions. Always read the docs before asking questions. ;)

Comment: Sorry, very new to this and only got told to ask my question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest solving the problem step by step.

1. Check the [`Date` object documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). There are methods that return the day, month, and year.
2. Add leading "0" when you need it. For instance, like this: `${value < 10 ? '0' : ''}${value}`.
3. Concatenate the strings:

```js
`${dayString}-${monthString}-${date.getFullYear()}`
```

```js
let date = new Date()
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);

const day = date.getDate();
const month = date.getMonth();
const dayString = `${day < 10 ? '0' : ''}${day}`;
const monthString = `${month < 10 ? '0' : ''}${month}`;
const formatted = `${dayString}-${monthString}-${date.getFullYear()}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const event = new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7));

var day = event.getDate();
var month = event.getMonth();
var year = event.getFullYear();

var date = day + '-' + month + '-' + year;

date.toString();
```

I did find a fix for my issues no more comments are necessary

Comment: I submitted an answer. Your code doesn't had leading "0". And `date.toString()` is redundant. `date` in that code is already a string.

Comment: Really shows how new I am to all of this.

I am getting a referenceError: day is not defined with your code.

Comment: I tested the code. If you remove `const day = date.getDate();`, you'll get “ReferenceError: day is not defined”.